# Basic if, else-if script not working as intended

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, logic

This basic script is supposed to compare two input values, and output the larger value--0 if both values are same. But I seem to have made a mistake, as the output is always 0. If you can spot the error, I would be very grateful. Also, I know there are many ways to do this, but I am practicing my logic; so I want stick to this structure.
Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int bigger(int, int);
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, answer;
    cout << "Enter two numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    answer == bigger(num1, num2);
    cout << "The bigger number is " << answer << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int bigger(int a, int b)
{
    int max;
    if(a > b)
    {
    max = a;
    }
    else if(a = b)
    {
        max = 0;
    }
    else {
    max = b;
        }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: what do you get if you print out `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: answer = bigger(num1, num2) would only perform the function twice. I did it and got the same answer.

Comment: I'd write it like this: `if (a == b) return 0; else return a < b ? b : a;`. Well, okay, in truth, I'd do this: `return a == b ? 0 : a < b ? b : a;`, but that would draw accusations of unreadability from people who haven't seen this kind of usage before.

Comment: @Pete When a and b are the same, why is the maximum 0 instead of a?

Comment: @FredOverflow - because that's what the stated requirement is: "0 if both values are the same".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else if(a = b)
```

should be

```
else if(a == b)
```

and

```
answer == bigger(num1, num2)
```

should be

```
answer = bigger(num1, num2)
```

Comment: also look at: answer == bigger(num1, num2);

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the assignment operator (=) for the comparision operator (==) in this statement

```
else if(a = b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
answer == bigger(num1, num2)
```

should be

```
answer = bigger(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing equality (`==`) and assignment (`=`).

Answer (score 0):

if(a = b)
has to be
if(a == b)

Answer (score 0):

Except for the `"=="` vs `"="` confusion that was already pointed out, I would also suggest you to use when it's possible the ternary operator. In your function you could have something like this:
`if(a == b)
        return 0;
   else
       return (a > b ? a : b);`